# WordPress: Get and display posts which have the same term

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called `type`. Type has the following options:

- Blog
- Case study
- Webinar

When on a post, I want to showcase posts which have the same type. I.e. if you're on a case study, I want it to display other case studies.

The maximum related posts I want to show is two, but if there is only one post that has that tag, then I only want it to display one.

Not sure where my query is falling apart:

```
global $post;

$blog_type = get_terms('type');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID ),
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post__not_in'   => array($post->ID ),
    'terms' => $blog_type,
);

$relatedPosts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `tax_query` here:

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'type', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $term_list
        )
    )
);

$relatedPosts = new WP_Query( $args );
```